# Azure Application Gateway Error 502

Tags: azure

Im setting up a web app in an App Service environment with Application Gateway
I constantly get error 502. I have set up custom probe and no NSG currently  on app gateway subnet so that shouldnt be an issue. On the App service Environment subnet NSG have allowed traffic from the APP Gateway subnet in for health probes but stiil get that annoying 502 error. My backend health in the app gateway always shows such a useful error message of " Unhealthy Unknown error. Please try again."
Been trying again and again and always same error!

Comment: Yes but I have a custom probe set up to check the hostname of the webapp eg myapp.mydomain.com. it's set to use HTTPS . A .pfx and .cer have been added to the web app. The certificate also uploaded to app gateway and the web app and also bindings added. What else can I configure ? The backend pool of the app gateway points to the IP of the load balancer in the app service environment

Answer (score 0):

As we have no way of knowing what is wrong with your app we cant help you, but if the backend health shows errors application gateway wont route traffic to the application. you need to fix your probes and it will work.

By default a probe is considered healthy for application gateway if it received HTTP response 200-399.

Comment: Azure diagnostic shows web app running ok. A VM can connect to the load balancer IP ok, so web app is running ok? Not sure why the app gateway is saying unhealthy. The IP of the load balancer pointing to the web app is also ok as the VM can connect . This is the same IP in the backend pool of the app gateway. With regards to the probe what URL should it check ? The IP of the load balancer, in the app service environment, the hostname of the web app in the app service environment or the custom host name of the web app ?

Comment: start by reducing complexity, make it work without end-to-end ssl

Comment: I will try that , also with the probe what URL needs to be checked , the URL of the webapp the App service environment uses or the custom host name added to  the web app or the IP of the load balancer in the app service environment ?